# How to configure the sealer account for a private Clique PoA network in Pantheon

Tags: poa, clique, pantheon, besu

Pantheon is the new Java-based Ethereum node targeting the enterprise setups.

I am trying to get my geth clique private network running on pantheon, but since pantheon has no account management, I am wondering how to setup the sealer account required for "mining" the blocks in Clique-PoA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pantheon (0.8.1) has no account management. It will only create a server private key, which is stored unencrypted in datadir/key. This key will also be used as the sealer account in Clique-PoA. Hence the public address stored in extraData in genesis.json has to correspond to this private key.

Comment: I confirm this is the way to go with Pantheon 0.8.1, we may provide another way in future release but nothing is designed yet.